# An exercise in Do Carmo's riemannian geometry after chapter11 'the morse index theorem'.

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let me put the picture of this exercise below:
[image]

Exercise 2 mentioned in the hint is the following:
[image]
My question is that in the hint, in order to show K=1 one must prove that the multiplicity of the conjugate point q in each geodesic from p is all n-1, but I don't know how to prove that. It seems only clear to me in 2 dimensional case. Any help will be appreciated.